# java load a file from a folder but the project is a module

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project **parent project** that contains 5 modules.

the *public static main* is located in the first module.

the first module calls the fifth module. the fifth module loads a file from a folder. the hiracicy of all everything together are:

```
module1
module2
module5
     config(this folder)
         plugings.xml (this file)
```

in the fifth modules, i want to load the `plugins.xml`, i do here:

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("moquette.path", null);

File filePluginsConfiguration = new File(configPath,
                "config/plugins.conf");
        if (!filePluginsConfiguration.exists()) {
            LOG.warn(String
                    .format("parsing not existing file %s, so fallback on default plugin configurations!",
                            filePluginsConfiguration.getAbsolutePath()));
```

i know know it is no correct, because moquette.path is points to a diffirent folder. but i don't know how can i point it to my plugins.xml file

could you help please

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by copying the module5 config folder into your **classpath**.

In ***Maven***, you can use [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to do it:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>module5/config</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, a file in the classpath is more useful and modular than a file 'in the file system'.

Place the file in `src/main/resources/some/package/plugins.conf', then use the Guava resources class to access it (there is a more verbose straight JRE alternative).

```
 URL url = Resources.getResource("/some/package/plugins.conf");
 String text = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Or get a stream or a reader with other methods of the Resources class. In any case, the file can 'live' in module (a) and be consumed in module (b).